# How to copy values from one array to another in C with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to copy the values from one array to another using strictly pointer arithmetic. This is the code I have right now:

```
   int *p;
   int arraySize = 20;

   int array[arraySize];     

   for (p = array; p< array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
        int random = rand() % 200;
        *p = random;
   }

   for (p = array; p< array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
        printf("%d\t%x\n", *p, p);
   }

   //the code above works fine

   printf("\n");

   //grow the new array by one to insert value at end later
   int array2[(arraySize+1)];

   int *p2;

   for(p2 = array2; p2< array2+(sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int)); p2++){
       *(p2) = *(p);
   }

   for(p2 = array2; p2< array2+(sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int)); p2++){
       printf("%d\t%x\n", *p2, p2);
   }
```

But when i run the code all that is outputted is 0 at each of the memory locations. what am i doing wrong that is preventing the values from being copied over?

Comment: `p` is not incremented.

Comment: The problem with your code is that it changes `p2`, but it never changes `p`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: doing p++ gives random numbers mixed with some zeros as output in the memory locations

Comment: Eugene and das have both identified the problem; I'm just here to ask---why do it this way?  When you use the `[x]` syntax, `*(ptr + (x * sizeof(int)))` is exactly what the compiler is doing (where `int` is the array type, as this example)...

Comment: because it is a requirement in our assignment. but when incrementing p with p++ it is not giving the correct output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this loop where you're copying from `*p` to `*p2`:

```
for(p2 = array2; p2< array2+(sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int)); p2++){
    *(p2) = *(p);
}
```

You increment `p2` but never increment `p` and you never reset `p` to point back to the beginning of `array`. At the beginning of this loop, `p` is pointing at the location just off the end of `array`. Change your loop to this:

```
for(p2 = array2, p = array; p2 < array2 + (sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int)) - 1; p2++, ++p){
    *(p2) = *(p);
}
```